# Error :- TypeError: add_argument() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argument'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

При коде:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options)
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
browser.implicitly_wait(50)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('ytd-button-renderer.ytd-masthead:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1) > paper-button:nth-child(1)').click()
print('Нажала.Что дальше, изволите?')
browser.close()
```

Выдаётся ошибка:

> Error :- TypeError: add_argument() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argument'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `Options` метод `add_argument()` определен [так](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/firefox/options.html#Options.add_argument):

```
def add_argument(self, argument):
    """Add argument to be used for the browser process."""
    if argument is None:
        raise ValueError()
    self._arguments.append(argument)
```

Как вы видите:

1. Этот метод имеет 2 аргументы: `self` и `argument`.
2. Этот метод *не возвращает ничего осмысленного* (и так возвращает `None`), и так *не имеет смысла сохранить его результат* (в какой-то переменной).

Ваш код

```
options = Options.add_argument('-headless')
```

на правой странице применяет метод `add_argument()` *прямо на класс* `Options`, и так он ожидает эти 2 аргументы (`self` и `argument`), но вы предоставляете только 1 (`'-headless'`), и так второй аргумент (`argument`) отсуствует.

Но метод `add_argument()` нет методом *класса* - он не назначенный для применения на *объект*. Это видно из названия `self` для первого аргумента. При применении метода на *объект* (класса `Options`) аргумент `self` не приводится - он будет автоматически (неявно) заполнен ссылкой на объект, который метод вызвал. Просто

```
имя_объекта.add_argument('-headless')
```

возможно понимать как

```
add_argument(имя_объекта, '-headless')
```

Отсюда следует, что вам нужен *объект* класса Options, который методом `add_argument()` прямо измените и потом его используете как параметр - вместо

```
options = Options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options)
```

(в вашем коде) используйте (так как вы назвали вашу переменную `options`) этот код:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Answer (score 5):

Для решения нужно было для начала создать объект *Options* и только потом добавлять нужный аргумент.

```
# Создаём объект
options = Options()
# Добавляем аргумент 
options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```